# I want to ditch my SSD/HDD setup. What's the easiest way to get everything from my SSD, onto my HDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I currently have an SSD, and an HDD set up on my computer, but I cannot care enough for the management issues.

Is there a simple way to transfer all the files from the SSD, onto the HDD, including boot information, etc., so that my computer only uses the HDD, even to start up?

In other words, after the procedure, if I pulled out the SSD, the computer wouldn't even know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be difficult for several reasons, the biggest one would be Windows itself. If Windows suddenly boots up from a different hard drive, it will suspect that it has been illegally moved to a new PC and probably ask you to reactivate.

You would probably be best off by moving your data to the HDD and reinstalling Windows on it. Sorry I can't give you an easier answer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would get a bigger SSD and install everything on it.  http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA24G1GC6489   The speed advantage of an SSD can not be ignored.  What kind of data is already on the hard drive?  Depending on experience level backing up your data,unplugging SSD and reload everything on the hard drive could be easier.

**Note:  I did not say faster**

Comment: Don't SSDs eventually die out with a lot of use?

Comment: The amount of use it takes you will never reach.  I have 9+ running 24/7/365 for 3+ years with no issue.  In the same period I have had 3 hard drive failures.  LONG term **all** devices die.  SSD has tons of spare sectors to make wear leveling a non issue.

Comment: What if I need to read/write a lot?

Comment: @user89 define a lot in gb/day of writing only.

Comment: @user89 reading has no effect at all on the life span of the drive just the writing.

Comment: About 50 GB a day of writing.

Comment: http://www.anandtech.com/show/7173/samsung-ssd-840-evo-review-120gb-250gb-500gb-750gb-1tb-models-tested/3  If we had the make and model of your SSD we might be able to look it up.  Using 242tb which is 247808gb/50 (gb/day) = 4956 days.

Answer (score 0):

There are several excellent applications out there both free and paid that do what you ask.  Since these things change, as per SE policy, I'll not name them here but instead point you to doing some research using your favorite search engine.

Comment: Wow! This was the most helpful answer here! Thanks!!!